# VSCode подсвечивает строку жёлтым цветом

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

VSCode подсвечивает мне строку delete [] arr1; жёлтым цветом и код дальше не идёт, хотя никаких ошибок в вкладке problems не выдаёт. Я скинул другу код и у него в том же VSCode всё работает. Почему у меня останавливается в этом месте код?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int number, n, c, i;
   cout << "Input number\n";
   cin >> number;
   n = number;
   c=-1;
   while (n>0)
   {
      n=n/10;
      c++;
   }
   i=1;
      int *arr1 = new int[c];
      while (c>=0)
      {
         arr1[i]=int(number/pow(10,c)) % 10;
         cout<<i<<"  "<<arr1[i]<<endl;
         i++;
         c--;
      }
      cout<<arr1[2]<<endl;
      delete [] arr1;
      int asdf;
      cin>>asdf;
      cout<<asdf+10;
   return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установите visual studio community и не ломайте мозг, а насчет кода скажу одно, будьте внимателней.

Comment: При обращении к элементу массива следует убедится, что индекс находится в рамках диапазона индексов элемента массива.